# TurtleBot on Jade ROS

Tags: turtlebot, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I face a problem while running ~$ roslaunch turtlebot_example turtlebot_gazebo.launch
. I see on the website http://wiki.ros.org/action/show/Robots/TurtleBot?action=show&redirect=TurtleBot
The latest officially supported release is for indigo.

Is there any solutions for tackling this problem?

The Result while running command line is :
[turtlebot_gazebo.launch] is neither a launch file in package [turtlebot_example] nor is [turtlebot_example] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241166/turtlebot-on-jade-ros/) by [marwa eldiwiny](https://answers.ros.org/users/27638/marwa-eldiwiny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The TurtleBot stack is only targeting the long term support releases. All packages are in Indigo and most are in Kinetic already. There are no plans to release TurtleBot packages for Jade.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marwa eldiwiny](https://answers.ros.org/users/27638/marwa-eldiwiny/) on 2016-08-07**:
SO can I install kinetic on Ubuntu 15.05

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-08-08**:
I'm not sure what you mean by 15.05: The target platforms are defined in [REP 3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#kinetic-kame-may-2016-may-2021)